# How to traverse a directory in python?

Tags: python, directory-structure

I have this code:

```
def traverse_dir(fd):      

    for dir_path,subpaths,files in os.walk(fd): 
        print dir_path,subpaths
        for file in files:
            print "file:%s"  %file

def traverse_func(arg,dirname,files):   

    print dirname
    for file in files:
            print "file:%s"  %file

os.path.walk(r".",traverse_func,())
```

Should I use `os.walk()` or `os.path.walk()`, and why?

Or is there any other better method?

Comment: `os.path.walk` does not exist in Python 3.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: oh I use python(x,y), it does not support  python3 ?

Comment: What is `python(x,y)`?

Comment: code.google.com/p/pythonxy

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: it is python distribution for Windows that is claimed to be “science-oriented”.

Comment: @王王王: if you’re so much attached to using windows and want a “scientific” python distribution, I advise that you use at least something close to [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the Python version you use. In Python 2 there is `os.path.walk()` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.walk)) but it has been deprecated and replaced with `os.walk()` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)) in Python 3.

Python(x,y) you claim to be using in comments, [seems to be based on Python 2](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/wiki/Downloads).

Answer (score 2):

os.walk(dir) returns a tuple with you must unpack.

```
for a, b, c in os.walk(dir):
  print("{} contains the directories {} and the files {}".format(a, b, c))
```

It's quite simple really.

For Python 3.6+ you can simplify this a bit:

```
for a, b, c in os.walk(dir):
  print(f"{a} contains the directories {b} and the files {c}")
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`os.path.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.walk) function is deprecated and is no longer available in Python 3. For that reason you should prefer [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).

`os.walk()` can also follow symbolic links to directories by setting the `followlinks` parameter to `True`. To do the same for `os.path.walk()` you must specifically check whether each directory is a sym link, and resolve it yourself. There are a couple of other possibly useful options for `os.walk()`, so overall, choose it over `os.path.walk()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve same with.

**os.listdir() + recursive**

```
def traverseFolder(ROOT):

    for entry in os.listdir(ROOT):
        path = os.path.join(ROOT,entry)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            traverseFolder(path)  #call to process sub-directory
        else:
            fhand = open(path,'r')
            data = fhand.read()
            ......


traverseFolder('path/someFolder')
```